# ConsoleBuffer' object has no attribute 'isatty'

Tags: apache-spark, deep-learning, databricks

I'm doing image classification using sparkdl on databricks community edition.
I added all the library's.
i have created data-frame using the image data.

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from sparkdl import DeepImageFeaturizer 

featurizer = DeepImageFeaturizer(inputCol="image", outputCol="features", modelName="InceptionV3")
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=20, regParam=0.05, elasticNetParam=0.3, labelCol="label")
p = Pipeline(stages=[featurizer, lr])

p_model = p.fit(train_df)   




    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2468766328144961> in <module>()
      7 p = Pipeline(stages=[featurizer, lr])
      8 
----> 9 p_model = p.fit(train_df)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    104                 if isinstance(stage, Transformer):
    105                     transformers.append(stage)
--> 106                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    107                 else:  # must be an Estimator
    108                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the title of your question, it sounds like you're hitting a `AttributeError: 'ConsoleBuffer' object has no attribute 'isatty'` error in a Databricks Python notebook.

If you are using [Databricks Runtime 3.3](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/3.3.html) or later then this bug should be fixed.

In earlier Databricks Runtime releases, you should be able to work around this problem by monkeypatching `sys.stdout` by running the following code snippet at the beginning of your Python notebook:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.isatty = lambda: False
sys.stdout.encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Databricks' Python REPL overrides `sys.stdout` to use our own `ConsoleBuffer` class and prior to Databricks Runtime 3.3 this class did not implement the `isatty` and `encoding` methods.

Source: I'm a Databricks employee who worked on this bugfix.