# Flask Error - AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty'

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am working on Flask App that uses MongoDb and I am getting this: "NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty'". I have been researching and saw that some people resolved this by installing Anaconda 64 bit. However I am already running 64bit version on window 10.

The code for my flask app is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, redirect
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import scrape_mars

# create instance of Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mars_app"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

#  create route that renders index.html template
@app.route("/")
def index():
    mars = mongo.db.mars.find_one()
    return render_template("index.html", mars=mars)


@app.route("/scrape")
def scrape():
    mars = mongo.db.mars
    mars_data = scrape_mars.scrape()
    mars.update(
        {},
        mars_data,
        upsert=True
    )
    return redirect("http://localhost:5000/", code=302)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The error I get is on last line app.run() and its:

> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'isatty'

I have tried running this in pycharm but I`m getting same message. Any idea what to try next?

Comment: kindly post the error message

Comment: @ImtinanAzhar - Hi, I updated the question with error message.

Comment: kindly post the whole stack trace, this is not sufficient to asses the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can hava a try with the method as below by Mr Josh Rosen,

[ConsoleBuffer' object has no attribute 'isatty'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069239/consolebuffer-object-has-no-attribute-isatty)

Comment: do you know the cause of the flask error? if yes, please explain it as an answer.